# Are there any build in function to find total sum of a double array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to find *maximum number* in a `double[]` array. I also want a *total sum* of all the elements of a `double[]` array. Has C# provided such *basic function* for `double[]` arrays in C#?

```
double[] array = new double[2] {1, 2}

double max = ? // should be 2
double sum = ? // should be 3
```

Comment: Try *Linq* `using System.Linq; ... double[] myArray = ...; double sum = myArray.Sum();` Same for maximum: `double max = myArray.Max();`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you say more about what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by a 'double' array (a 2 dimensional array or an array of doubles)? Do you mean a single value or the sum of each dimension separately?

Comment: I just need the total sum a single 1D array Eg double[] array = new double[2] {1, 2}. The sum would be 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, we use *Linq* for this (querying):

```
 using System.Linq;

 ... 

 double[] array = ...

 ...

 double max = array.Max();
 double sum = array.Sum();
```

The only difficulty you can run into is that `Max` *throws exception* when `array` is *empty*. In this case you can check for `Any` (or `array.Length > 0`):

```
 double max = array.Any()     // or even array.Length > 0
   ? array.Max()              // array has items, business as usual
   : double.NegativeInfinity; // empty array, some default value

 double sum = array.Sum();    // 0.0 if array is empty
```

In case you have *multidimensional* array, you have to turn into `1D`; you can do it with a help of `Cast`:

```
 double[,] array = new double[,] {
   {1, 2},
   {3, 4},
 };

 double sum = array.Cast<double>().Sum();
 double max = array.Cast<double>().Max();
```

In case of *jagged* array in order to *flatten* it add `SelectMany`:

```
 double[][] array = new double[][] {
   new double[] {1, 2, 3},
   new double[] {4, 5}, 
 };

 double sum = array.SelectMany(line => line).Sum();
 double max = array.SelectMany(line => line).Max();
```